# Is there an adjective meaning a wide trajectory?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I need an adjective that tells that the trajectory of a projectile (in this case, a snowball) was wider than higher and fills in this blank:

"The _____ snowball hit the wall the other team made to protect us from snowballs, but my team started lobbing the snowballs."

Comment: Ah, so kinda opposite of / complement to *lob* (thrown in a high arc, so the horizontal distance travelled isn't great, but it's easier to catch for the same reason).

Comment: +DanBron Exactly. I edited the question to use the word _lob_.

Comment: The only way a trajectory can be "wide" is if it's "wide of the mark".  Do you simply mean "low"?

Comment: @HotLicks *Low* definitely gets the idea across immediately. But it would be fun and exciting if there were a more specific (or technical, even) word.

Comment: The trajectory is *flat* (or *relatively flat*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not actually describing the snowball, but the snowball's trajectory, I think you'll fail to have much luck with this.
I'd advise changing the sentence to "the snowball, traveling a/n ____ trajectory, hit the other team's wall".
On a side note, physically speaking I'd imagine it's rather difficult to get enough spin on a snowball so that it arcs in a horizontal manner. Are you sure you don't just mean "low"?

Anyway, I believe the word you're looking for for the trajectory is **[sweeping](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweeping)** (see the "Full Definitions" section of definition 2, beneath the "Simple Definitions" section).

Comment: This word seems to mean _effect_, not _trajectory_. I need a word for the latter.

Comment: It does refer to trajectory, as well. See the first full definition of the link I just added (the full definitions are below the "simple definitions" section)

Answer (score 1):

The best I can think of is **low-arcing**. As David McKnight said, this is actually describing the trajectory, but *"The low-arcing snowball"* still works. Following David's suggestion, there's also **flat** as in *"the snowball, travelling in a flat trajectory..."*.